# Debugging a choice with only 3 answers in Python

Tags: python, debugging, while-loop, user-input

I have an input and there is only three possible choices the user can make and I am currently trying to debug it right now with no luck. I tried using the way that it is done with number values however it has not worked and will not let me type anything at all in now. I have also tried to see if I could do user_choice != to  the variable (values) however I have had the same output as before.

```
while loser != 'Lose':
    key_error = True
    while key_error:
        try:
            user_choice = str(input('Enter your choice: '))
            user_choice = (user_choice.lower())
            if user_choice != 'r' or user_choice != 'p' or user_choice != 's':
                print(" Please enter either r, s or p")
            else:
                key_error = False
        except ValueError:
            print( " Invalid input, Please enter either r, s or p: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

`if user_choice != 'r' or user_choice != 'p' or user_choice != 's':` will always be true, since it can't be all three at once, and all it takes is one of the `or` parts for that if statement to be true. Try this:

`if user_choice not in ('r', 'p', 's'):`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes i understand what you mean. I didn't know about the not in function, thank you for teaching it to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
while loser != 'Lose':
       while True:
            user_choice = str(input('Enter your choice: '))
            user_choice = (user_choice.lower())
            if user_choice != 'r' and user_choice != 'p' and user_choice != 's':
                print(" Please enter either r, s or p")
            else:
                break
```

This will continue executing your program only if the user has entered something other than r, s or p.